# Is my ceramic hob wired correctly?

Tags: electrical, kitchens

My 5.8kw ceramic hob has been wired into a 30 amp junction box with the electric ignition cable of the old gas hob and then wired into the cooker switch with .6 mm cooker cable. Is this correct wiring?

Comment: I understand what you are asking but in the US we go on wire gauge and my books are in my office , if you can provide the KW load for the new cooker we should be able to help.

Comment: What's the gauge (mm is fine) of the ignition cable from the old gas hob?

Comment: If by ignition cable you mean thin flex like on a toaster, then that's horribly wrong. It should have 4mm^2 or larger flex for that load.

Answer (score 1):

I Forgot about this one. 5.8KW on a 240V would only draw a little over 24 amps. in the U.S. this would require 10 Awg wire. A standard wire type THHN 10 Awg crosses over to 4.166 MM as the aprox diameter as listed in the NEC chapter 9 Table 5. I am surprised the cable is not melting this is way under sized.  To answer the question: No it is not correctly wired.